# Ubuntu stops auto-mounting flash drive

Tags: ubuntu, usb, gnome, mount, usb-flash-drive

It seems that after being up for a few days, my Ubuntu system refuses to auto-mount hot-plugged USB disks (i.e. flash drives). The output from dmesg shows that the kernel recognizes the device correctly.  The only solution I'm aware of at the moment is to reboot (logging out may work as well, but the impact is the same since I have a bunch of stuff open and it takes a few minutes to get everything situated after startup/login).

I thought gvfs-fuse-daemon was the thing responsible for managing filesystems in userspace, but killing and restarting that doesn't help.  Any other ideas?

(Ubuntu 9.10, gnome, 64-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a link to a solution I found. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Known_Problems_with_Auto-Loading

basically the rules file stop to exist and they cause problems.

Comment: Your link was broken, in the future perhaps copy/paste the contents, as well as source?: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Known_problems_with_auto-loading

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your installed packages especially `hal` and `dbus`.

If this doesn't work, please post which desktop you are running... (KDE, Gnome, etc?)

UPDATE: Apparently, this is a widespread problem after the last (Kernel) update... I recommend checking https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/564459 on a regular base for a solution.

Comment: Packages are all up-to-date (Gnome, Ubuntu 9.10).  Auto-mounting USB disks works for a while (whether they are plugged before boot or not), but at some point auto-mounting no longer works.

Comment: After it stops working, plug the USB disk in and post the output of the `mount` command.